# Vue.js compile errors with 'Number' prop type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

Im new to vue.js so sorry if this is just a simple error on my part.

I have an auto generated vue app, and have a custom component.

Now when I set a prop to type 'String' its fine, however when I set my prop to type 'Number' it fails with the following:

```
    props: {
        id: { type:String },
        value: { type:Number },
        labelText: { type:String },
    },
```

```
./src/components/form/NumberField.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/form/NumberField.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.number.constructor' in 'src/components/form'
```

I think maybe im missing something in the bable loader that I think is compiling the js.

Thanks for the help,

Dave

Comment: Try re-installing core-js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to onuriltan, did not realise core-js was not installed by default with the fresh vue.js app, after `npm install --save core-js` it works a treat, thanks :)